# Словообразовательный анализ слов "образование, образованный"

Tags: словообразование

Не могу понять, как правильно сделать словообразовательный анализ этих слов.

1) **Исторически все просто.** Еще во времена Даля существовал глагол ***образовать*** с соответствующим значением, а также производные слова: ***образовать –  образование, образовать – образованный, образованный – образованность.***

**Например:** Науки образовывают ум и знания. Ум человека образовывается легче, нежели сердце. Образованье ума и нрава. Образованный человек, получивший образованье. Образованье также степень или состоянье кого в сем деле, или образованность, состоянье образованного. [https://gufo.me/dict/dal/ображать](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

2) Но в настоящее время глагол ***образовать*** считается устаревшим, поэтому всё семейство «осиротело». И как тогда надо поступить?

**Вариант 1.** Считать, что глагол как бы существует, что видно из морфемного разбора: образова/ть – образова/нн/ый, образова/ни/е. Тогда по-прежнему будет: ***образовать –  образование, образовать – образованный?***

**Вариант 2.**  Глагол устарел, но осталось отглагольное существительное ***образование*** с тем же значением. Согласно толковому словарю:  ОБРАЗОВАНИЕ,   Процесс усвоения знаний; обучение, просвещение.  ОБРАЗОВАННЫЙ, Получивший образование, имеющий разносторонние знания.

Тогда ***образование*** – непроизводное слово и от него образуется слово ***образованный***? Этот вариант мне кажется наименее приемлемым.

**Вариант 3.**  Переход в другую часть речи, изменение значения

***Образовать – образование*** (название действия) – ***образование*** (новое значение).

***Образовать – образованный*** (прич.) – ***образованный*** (прил.)

**Так какой вариант верен и по какому источнику его можно проверить?** Также хотелось бы однозначно определиться, а не считать, что они все верны (выбирай какой нравится). Есть же какой-то школьный норматив для разбора этих слов.